# React Native version mismatch 0.59.1 > 0.61.2

Tags: ios, react-native

After upgrading react-native from 0.59.10 to 0.61.2 the app does not load. It's stuck on the splash screen and giving me a version mismatch.

**XCode logs showing:**

```
JavaScript version: 0.59.1
Native version: 0.61.2-undefined
```

(I find the 'undefined' part above also quite strange)

**I've tried the following:**

- Removing node modules;
- Removing Pods and reinstalling;
- watchman watch-del-all && react-native start --reset-cache;
- Checked through my project for any 0.59.10 versions (nothing found);
- Made sure all my terminal windows were closed;
- Used react-native-clean-project;
- Uninstalled app in Simulator;
- Reinstalled the Xcode simulator.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "-",
  "ios_version": "1.2.21",
  "android_version": "1.2.21",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "clean": "react-native-clean-project"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.2.1",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^3.2.1",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "bugsnag-react-native": "^2.23.2",
    "d3-scale": "^3.0.0",
    "d3-shape": "^1.3.5",
    "i18n-js": "^3.3.0",
    "lodash.memoize": "^4.1.2",
    "lottie-ios": "^3.1.3",
    "lottie-react-native": "^3.2.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "native-base": "^2.12.1",
    "prettier": "^1.17.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "qs": "^6.7.0",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-devtools-core": "github:msand/react-devtools-core#4c30959",
    "react-native": "0.61.2",
    "react-native-clean-project": "^3.2.4",
    "react-native-code-push": "^5.6.1",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-localize": "^1.1.4",
    "react-native-onesignal": "^3.4.2",
    "react-native-permissions": "^2.0.2",
    "react-native-rate": "^1.1.7",
    "react-native-restart": "0.0.12",
    "react-native-safari-view": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-shimmer-placeholder": "^1.0.30",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^9.3.5",
    "react-native-svg-charts": "^5.2.0",
    "react-native-touch-id": "^4.4.1",
    "react-navigation": "4.0.10",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-axios-middleware": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.2",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.6.2",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.5",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "eslint": "^6.5.1",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.56.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.9.0",
    "eslint-config-rallycoding": "^3.2.0",
    "reactotron-react-native": "^3.6.4",
    "reactotron-redux": "^3.1.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./src/assets/fonts/"
    ]
  }
}
```

**podfile**

```
    platform :ios, '9.0'
    require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform- 
    ios/native_modules'
    project 'cryptohopperMobile',
      'Debug' => :debug,
      'Staging' => :release,
      'Release' => :release

    target '-' do
      pod 'FBLazyVector', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBLazyVector"
      pod 'FBReactNativeSpec', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBReactNativeSpec"
      pod 'RCTRequired', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/RCTRequired"
      pod 'RCTTypeSafety', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/TypeSafety"
      pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native'
      pod 'React-CoreModules', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React/CoreModules'
      pod 'React-Core/DevSupport', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
      pod 'React-RCTActionSheet', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS'
      pod 'React-RCTAnimation', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation'
      pod 'React-RCTBlob', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob'
      pod 'React-RCTImage', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image'
      pod 'React-RCTLinking', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS'
      pod 'React-RCTNetwork', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network'
      pod 'React-RCTSettings', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings'
      pod 'React-RCTText', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text'
      pod 'React-RCTVibration', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Vibration'
      pod 'React-Core/RCTWebSocket', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
      pod 'React-cxxreact', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/cxxreact'
      pod 'React-jsi', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi'
      pod 'React-jsiexecutor', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsiexecutor'
      pod 'React-jsinspector', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsinspector'
      pod 'ReactCommon/jscallinvoker', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
      pod 'ReactCommon/turbomodule/core', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
      pod 'Yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'
      pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
      pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
      pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'
      pod 'BugsnagReactNative', path: '../node_modules/bugsnag-react-native'

      permissions_path = '../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios'
      pod 'Permission-Notifications', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Notifications.podspec"

      target 'OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension' do
        pod 'OneSignal', '>= 2.9.3', '< 3.0'
      end

      target '-Tests' do
        inherit! :search_paths
        # Pods for testing
      end

      use_native_modules!
    end

    target '--tvOS' do
      # Pods for tvOS
      target '-tvOSTests' do
        inherit! :search_paths
        # Pods for testing
      end
    end
```

**react-native log-ios**

```
    NOTE:  Most system logs have moved to a new logging system.  See log(1) for more information.
    Oct  9 09:59:50 MBP-van-Kevin com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.A503B1AD-A2E6-4B6A-8BB0-8B836CDBB65A[27392] (com.apple.intents.intents-helper) <Warning>: Unknown key for Boolean: EnableTransactions
    Oct  9 09:59:50 MBP-van-Kevin com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.A503B1AD-A2E6-4B6A-8BB0-8B836CDBB65A[27392] (com.apple.intents.intents-helper) <Warning>: Unknown key for Boolean: EnablePressuredExit
    Oct  9 09:59:50 MBP-van-Kevin com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.A503B1AD-A2E6-4B6A-8BB0-8B836CDBB65A[27392] (com.apple.uifoundation-bundle-helper) <Warning>: Unknown key for Boolean: EnableTransactions
    Oct  9 09:59:50 MBP-van-Kevin com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.A503B1AD-A2E6-4B6A-8BB0-8B836CDBB65A[27392] (com.apple.uifoundation-bundle-helper) <Warning>: Unknown key for Boolean: EnablePressuredExit
    Oct  9 09:59:50 MBP-van-Kevin com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.A503B1AD-A2E6-4B6A-8BB0-8B836CDBB65A[27392] (com.apple.mobileslideshow.PhotosFileProvider[28289]) <Error>: assertion failed: 18G87: launchd_sim + 63769 [8D9B6CF1-070B-38FD-B74A-774E187D3032]: 0x16
    Oct  9 10:00:50 MBP-van-Kevin druid[28917] <Error>: assertion failed: 18G87 16G73: libxpc.dylib + 80528 [5846A329-63C0-3B4F-BC91-F30AF4CA6E30]: 0x7d
    Oct  9 10:00:50 MBP-van-Kevin Unknown[28917] <Error>:
    Oct  9 10:00:52 MBP-van-Kevin launchd_sim[27392] <Notice>: BUG in libdispatch client: mach_recv, monitored resource vanished before the source cancel handler was invoked { 0x7fb270a0bfa0[source], ident: 257795 / 0x3ef03, handler: 0x10b03c2d6 }
    Oct  9 10:01:07 MBP-van-Kevin cryptohopper_mobile[29274] <Error>: assertion failed: 18G87 16G73: libxpc.dylib + 80528 [5846A329-63C0-3B4F-BC91-F30AF4CA6E30]: 0x7d
    Oct  9 10:01:07 MBP-van-Kevin Unknown[29274] <Error>:
```

**XCode logs**

```
    2019-10-09 10:03:36.746016+0200 cryptohopper_mobile[31428:128970] libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:890: MGIsDeviceOneOfType is not supported on this platform.
    2019-10-09 10:03:36.900263+0200 cryptohopper_mobile[31428:128970] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /Users/kevinetore/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3356B7C4-EFA4-4639-B6EA-631D56E67BB5/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
    2019-10-09 10:03:36.900578+0200 cryptohopper_mobile[31428:128970] [MC] Reading from private effective user settings.
    2019-10-09 10:03:36.917791+0200 cryptohopper_mobile[31428:129053] App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.
    2019-10-09 10:03:36.917908+0200 cryptohopper_mobile[31428:129053] Cannot start load of Task <2C82020D-9EB0-4B61-B918-E0495956134D>.<1> since it does not conform to ATS policy
    2019-10-09 10:03:36.918088+0200 cryptohopper_mobile[31428:129051] Task <2C82020D-9EB0-4B61-B918-E0495956134D>.<1> finished with error - code: -1022
    2019-10-09 10:03:36.960 [info][tid:main][RCTRootView.m:293] Running application cryptohopper_mobile ({
        initialProps =     {
        };
        rootTag = 1;
    })
    2019-10-09 10:03:36.967546+0200 cryptohopper_mobile[31428:128970] ERROR: Error! iOS Simulator does not support push! Please test on a real iOS device. Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3010 "remote notifications are not supported in the simulator" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=remote notifications are not supported in the simulator}
    2019-10-09 10:03:37.099 [error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] React Native version mismatch.

    JavaScript version: 0.59.1
    Native version: 0.61.2-undefined

    Make sure that you have rebuilt the native code. If the problem persists try clearing the Watchman and packager caches with `watchman watch-del-all && react-native start --reset-cache`.
    2019-10-09 10:03:37.148 [error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] undefined is not an object (evaluating 's.Manager')
    2019-10-09 10:03:37.150 [fatal][tid:com.facebook.react.ExceptionsManagerQueue] Unhandled JS Exception: undefined is not an object (evaluating 's.Manager')
    2019-10-09 10:03:37.152 [error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
    2019-10-09 10:03:37.201 [fatal][tid:com.facebook.react.ExceptionsManagerQueue] Unhandled JS Exception: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
```

**react-native run-ios**

```
warn Your project is using deprecated "rnpm" config that will stop working from next release. Please use a "react-native.config.js" file to configure the React Native CLI. Migration guide: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/configuration.md
warn The following packages use deprecated "rnpm" config that will stop working from next release:
  - react-native-code-push: https://microsoft.github.io/code-push
Please notify their maintainers about it. You can find more details at https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/configuration.md#migration-guide.
error React Native CLI uses autolinking for native dependencies, but the following modules are linked manually:
  - bugsnag-react-native (to unlink run: "react-native unlink bugsnag-react-native")
This is likely happening when upgrading React Native from below 0.60 to 0.60 or above. Going forward, you can unlink this dependency via "react-native unlink <dependency>" and it will be included in your app automatically. If a library isn't compatible with autolinking, disregard this message and notify the library maintainers.
Read more about autolinking: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/autolinking.md
info Found Xcode workspace "cryptohopperMobile.xcworkspace"
info Building (using "xcodebuild -workspace cryptohopperMobile.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme cryptohopperMobile -destination id=A503B1AD-A2E6-4B6A-8BB0-8B836CDBB65A -derivedDataPath build/cryptohopperMobile")
............................................................
info Installing "build/cryptohopperMobile/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/cryptohopper_mobile.app"
info Launching "com.cryptohopper"
success Successfully launched the app on the simulator
```

**react-native info**

```
Binaries:
    Node: 12.11.1 - /usr/local/bin/node
    npm: 6.11.3 - /usr/local/bin/npm
    Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: iOS 12.4, macOS 10.14, tvOS 12.4, watchOS 5.3
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 3.4 AI-183.6156.11.34.5522156
    Xcode: 10.3/10G8 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  npmPackages:
    react: 16.9.0 => 16.9.0
    react-native: 0.61.2 => 0.61.2
  npmGlobalPackages:
    react-native-cli: 2.0.1
```

Any help is welcome if you need any more information please ask.

**Update**

It seems to be an Xcode Simulator debug mode issue. When I set the app with stage set to release and launch it on an actual device/simulator, it builds correctly.

Comment: Do you have upgraded it with `react-native upgrade` command? Have you resolved all conflicts?

Comment: Yes I've used `react-native upgrade` to update to the latest version. If I execute the command again it returns: ```Specified version "0.61.2" is already installed in node_modules and it satisfies "0.61.2" semver range. No need to upgrade```. Doesn't say anything about any conflicts.

Comment: This is just a guess, but I wonder if the issue has to do with the podfile including all the react native core directories.  I'm assuming you've cleaned the Xcode project and restarted

Comment: I did clean/restart Xcode. Regarding all the includes within the Podfile > I've used https://raw.githubusercontent.com/react-native-community/rn-diff-purge/release/0.61.2/RnDiffApp/ios/Podfile as a reference.

Comment: Also, the issue I'm having is only on iOS. Android seems to work fine on 0.61.2

Comment: It seems to be an Xcode Simulator debug mode issue. When I set the app with stage set to release and launch it on an actual device/simulator, it builds correctly.

Comment: @KevinEtore wow funny I just ran into this problem myself, sorry if it's an obvious question but what exactly do you mean by "set the app with stage set to release"

Comment: @waffl Did you also just upgrade your react native project? You can set the release stage under: product > schema > edit schema. I think the setting is called build configuration (not with my laptop to check this). I'll try to fix the debug configuration today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After creating a new `bundle.js` with `"build:ios": "react-native bundle --entry-file='index.js' --bundle-output='./ios/main.jsbundle' --dev=true --platform='ios'"`, it worked.

**Update**

This fix above only fixed a part of the issue. I noticed that after manually creating the iOS bundle, React Native did not create a new bundle on load/refresh. That was my first clue which reminded me in some changes I made in `AppDelegate.m`:

```
#if DEBUG
  return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
#else
  return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif
```

After changing back the `else` statement to what I had before `return [CodePush bundleURL];` it fixed the issue. I'm not sure what caused me to change it in the first place, I think it was the Codepush documentation.

Answer (score 0):

- If your project is not huge, you can save *.js files and make
  **react-native init** again
- But if you need to save a structure of your project you can migrate
  with [Upgrade Helper](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/)

Comment: I don't think react-native init is a good solution to a problem such as this. I've also used the upgrade-helper with `react-native-upgrade` to make sure I did not overlook something.

Comment: so you solved your issue, or have some problems yet?

Comment: still the same issue as I had before.

Comment: Try to delete the app, then build and launch on your device. If it doesn`t work try to check all your difference [Upgrade Helper](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/) again

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you need to add similar addition in your **Podfile**,
next to the project clause.
This will effectively configure your schemes for debugging or release.
It seems that RN v.60.x has some breaking changes in this regard, especially if you have multiple schemes and/or using react-native-schemes-manager.

```
project 'NameOfYourProject',
'Debug' => :debug,
'Release' => :release,
'FooDebug' => :debug,
'FooRelease' => :release
```

For more detailed info see

- [Github issue](https://github.com/thekevinbrown/react-native-schemes-manager/issues/76#issuecomment-522016998)
- [Podfile Syntax Reference](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#project)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've added the code in my Podfile (see Podfile code above) and executed: `cd ios/ && rm -rf Pods/ && pod install && cd ../`. Still getting:

```
2019-10-10 11:59:16.390 [error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] React Native version mismatch.

JavaScript version: 0.59.1
Native version: 0.61.2-undefined
```

Comment: @KevinEtore If I compare it to my Podfile config, you sohuld make sure "cryptohopperMobile" has "xcodeproj" file extension ("cryptohopperMobile.xcodeproj"). Also make sure the schemes names in this config chunk are exactly the same as in your XCODE project. This worked out perfectly for me

Comment: Strange, my project has the correct file extension and the scheme names are identical.

Comment: And if I'm right `project` in the `Podfile` is particularly used for custom build configurations. It should not be required for the default debug/release configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Hi @KevinEtore please remove all of your manually linked libraries and migrate all of them to CocoaPods. Seems you have forget to remove manually linked React Native libraries.

If you have already removed those manullay linked libs,

**Please try with Pod resetting**

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods
rm -rf Pods #inside the project ./ios folder
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*
pod deintegrate
pod setup
pod install
```

Comment: I've tried all the steps you mentioned before, the result is still the same error `React Native version mismatch`.

Answer (score 0):

I my case that issue was fixed after update other packages with deprecated submodules (they was deleted from React Native package)